# If a GEE task is described as "Running on Sever", can I shutdown my computer and chekck its result later?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google

I'm new in using Google Earth Engine and today I tried to export an image into Assets, but it seems that the task will take a long time to compute a result. I noticed that it says the task is "running on server", so I wonder if I can shutdown my computer/close the browser and check its result when I'm free?[image]

Comment: Yes, you can safely do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can leave the page/tab/browser.  When you log into the Earth Engine code editor again, and go to the Tasks tab, the Task should be there, reporting if it has finished.

Answer (score 1):

yes, since GEE is a cloud based server it has nothing do with your browser!